# kubectl port forwarding timeout issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

While using kubectl port-forward function I was able to succeed in port forwarding a local port to a remote port. However it seems that after a few minutes idling the connection is dropped. Not sure why that is so.

Here is the command used to portforward:

```
kubectl --namespace somenamespace port-forward somepodname 50051:50051
```

Error message:

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:50051 -> 50051
Forwarding from [::1]:50051 -> 50051
E1125 17:18:55.723715    9940 portforward.go:178] lost connection to pod
```

Was hoping to be able to keep the connection up

Comment: What's the status of that Pod?  If it's not restarting or failing. As it seems to me issue is related to session layer which is impacted by the pod's behaviour.

Comment: any chance you're on aks (azure)?

Comment: status of pod is ok ... nope not using azure

Comment: Seeing this consistently on a Kubernetes deployment within AWS. (strange there isn't more discussion)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Seems there is a 5 minute timeout that can be overridden with `kubelet` parameters:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19231

> If you want to pass something higher than 5 minutes (or unlimited) into your kubelets, you can specify the `streaming-connection-idle-timeout`. E.g.
>   `--streaming-connection-idle-timeout=4h` to set it to 4 hours. Or:
>   `--streaming-connection-idle-timeout=0` to make it unlimited.
>   (DEPRECATED: This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.)

Comment: I get `unknown flag: --streaming-connection-idle-timeout` when I try this.

Comment: @magnattic Would `--request-timeout` work? @RobotNerd has mentioned such in 2018 in a now deleted (by him/her) answer.

Comment: --request-timeout is a valid option but doesn't seem to work as expected...

Answer (score 48):

Setting kube's `streaming-connection-idle-timeout` to 0 should be a right solution, but if you don't want to change anything, you can use while-do construction

Format: `while true; do <<YOUR COMMAND HERE>>; done`

So just inputing in CLI: `while true; do kubectl --namespace somenamespace port-forward somepodname 50051:50051; done` should keep kubectl reconnecting on connection lost

Comment: Is there some solution for windows cmd?

Comment: Sorry @AndrewSneck, have no experience with win console. But as far as I know latest windows has unix cli built-in you should try it out

Comment: +1 that was the better solution for me: forwarding to kubernetes dashboard from a jumper host, where no kubelet is running

Comment: @AndrewSneck powershell: while ($true) { kubectl port-forward your-command-here }

Comment: kubectl process doesn't exit even when timeout(got such type of log: E0621 10:11:52.183060   20798 portforward.go:340] error creating error stream for port 9191 -> 9191: Timeout occured). so I doubt this while loop ever loops when timeout.

Comment: When I receive "lost connection to pod" message, kubectl exits.  There may be some merit in a loop.

Comment: In my situation the kubectl did not exist when timeout @user2563451

Comment: I'm having this issue but it didn't help in my case.

Answer (score 45):

I solved this by keeping the connection alive, e.g. using curl or nc.

Forward the port:

```
kubectl --namespace somenamespace port-forward somepodname 50051:50051
```

In another terminal, keep the connection alive by reaching out to the port every 10 seconds:

```
while true ; do nc -vz 127.0.0.1 50051 ; sleep 10 ; done
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually keeps the connection alive without changing anything on the server side. Putting the port-forward command in a loop will break long poll connections which is the main reason I have an issue with port-forward timing out in the first place.

Comment: This worked!  why? God knows ... where are the days of PLAIN C!  and unix pizza boxs...

Comment: Can you explain why it works, I am very curious.@Marcel

Comment: @Dolphin the port-forward command times out if it isn't used. The second command reaches out to the port and keeps it alive

Comment: It didn't help me unfortunately...

Answer (score 19):

For windows make such bat (God forgive me)

```
:1
oc port-forward PODNAME 8003:8080
goto 1
```

Comment: You are forgiven

Comment: This is still the best solution I could think for executing this command non stop.
Well I forgive you but not for my self to write this statement each time in almost 2021. I think this bug still exists in kubernetes side (Running cluster on linode btw)

Comment: There is no command named "oc" ..

Comment: oc is the command line for open shift (kubernetes variant), same command would work with kubectl.

Comment: @abarbaneld you are not god, god forgive you for this impersonation

Answer (score 2):

Problem with a simple `while true` approach is the `kubectl port-forward` does not crash in case of a timeout - sometimes, but not for every timeout.

I'm using the following workaround inspired by https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/78446#issuecomment-1497776898 which detects timeout in the output of `kubectl port-forward` and kills and restarts the commands proactively - the only solution amongst many I tried that works reliably.

There're still failure, but the connection recovers which most applications can handle well.

```
NAMESPACE=$1
SERVICE=$2
LOCAL_PORT=$3
K8S_SERVICE_PORT=$4

command="kubectl -n $NAMESPACE port-forward svc/$SERVICE $LOCAL_PORT:$K8S_SERVICE_PORT"
while true; do
      echo "--> $command"
      $command 2>&1 >/dev/null |
      while IFS= read -r line
      do
            echo "### $line"
            if [[ "$line" == *"portforward.go"* ]]; then
                  echo "Restarting port forwarding $command"
                  exit 1
            else
                  exit 0
            fi
      done
      sleep 0.1
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            break;
      fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your Kubernetes cluster behind a load balancer (like HAProxy), it could happen that the timeout configured in kubelet is bigger than the timeout configured in the HAProxy.

For instance, the `streamingConnectionIdleTimeout` setting in Kubelet by default is 4h:

```sh
$ kubectl proxy --port=8001 &
$ NODE_NAME="XXXX"; curl -sSL "http://localhost:8001/api/v1/nodes/${NODE_NAME}/proxy/configz" | jq '.kubeletconfig|.kind="KubeletConfiguration"|.apiVersion="kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1"' | grep streaming
  "streamingConnectionIdleTimeout": "4h0m0s",
```

But if in HAProxy (or your preferred LB) you have these settings:

```
defaults
  timeout client 1m
  timeout server 1m
...
```

Trying to execute a port-forwarding will timeout if you don't have any activity over the app:

```sh
$ date; kubectl port-forward service/XXXX 1234:80
Mon Jul  5 10:58:20 CEST 2021
Forwarding ...
# after a minute
E0705 10:59:21.217577   64160 portforward.go:233] lost connection to pod
```

In order to fix this, a solution would be to increase the timeout (be careful with this, because depending on your cluster it can have undesirable effects) or bypass the LB when doing port-forwarding connecting directly to the API server (if your environment allows it).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bash function that I use, to bypass port-forward with timeout issues:

> ```
> function pfpod(){
> pod=$1
> portloc=$2
> portrem=$3
> while true
>   do
>     podname=`kubectl get pods -o name | awk -F'/' '{print $2}'| grep "$pod"| head -1`
>     kubectl port-forward $podname $portloc:$portrem
> done
> }
> ```

I have added a kubectl call to match partial podname, in case you have many pods for a deployment, you can just give partial name and the top pod will be used. Otherwise you can also provide the full pod name.

Sample Usage:

> pfpod elasticsearch 9201 9200