# Getting a connection timeout issue with port forwarding in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-mac

I'm running a k8 cluster on Docker for Mac. To allow a connection from my database client to my mysql pod, I use the following command `kubectl port-forward mysql-0 3306:3306`. It works great, however a few hours later I get the following error `E0201 18:21:51.012823   51415 portforward.go:233] lost connection to pod`.

I check the actual mysql pod, and it still appears to be running. This happens every time I run the `port-forward` command.

I've seen the following answer here: [kubectl port forwarding timeout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484312/kubectl-port-forwarding-timeout-issue) and the solution is to use the following flag `--streaming-connection-idle-timeout=0` but the flag is now deprecated.

So following on from there, It appears that I have to set that parameter via a kubelet config file ([config file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/))? I'm unsure on how I could achieve this as Docker for Mac runs as a daemon and I don't manually start the cluster.

Could anyone send me a code example or instructions as to how i could configure `kubectl` to set that flag so my port forwarding won't have timeouts?

Comment: You should run your database client inside the cluster, or if you can't do that, expose the database using something like a NodePort service.  `kubectl port-forward` isn't designed to be a permanent connection into the cluster.

Comment: Documentation does suggest setting that flag to `0` would establish a permanent connection though? Would you know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Port forwards are generally for short term debugging, not “hours”. What you probably want is a NodePort type service which you can then connect to directly.

Comment: For how much time port forward works? @coderanger